# Problems Drawing Image

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to draw an `EncodedImage` and graphics. I read [this](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html) and I'm still having some issues. What am I doing wrong?

```
InputStream imageIn = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), GraphicsController.errorImgPath);
    try {

        g.drawImage(EncodedImage.createImage(imageIn), 50, 50);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Getting this error:

`ERROR: resources must reside in the root directory thus must start with a '/' character in Codename One! Invalid resource: errorImage.png
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: ERROR: resources must reside in the root directory thus must start with a '/' character in Codename One! Invalid resource: errorImage.png
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

errorImagePath should be something like `/MyImage.png` and can't be `MyImage.png` or `/com/mypackage/MyImage.png`.

However, what you are doing could be really bad... You are loading an image for every drawing `paint()` callback and that can be REALLY expensive as loading an image takes time. I suggest loading the image to RAM beforehand and drawing separately.